# File Mapping to copy faster?

Tags: delphi, memory-mapped-files, file-copying

I made ​​an application to copy a file using thread and the method of TFileStream, but I was a little disappointed with the speed, especially when copying large files. Then I heard about the *file mapping*, which apparently could certainly yield a method of copying a lot faster since access to the files would be much faster.

I'm a beginner so I'm trying to, but I have not managed to copy a file via file mapping. (The file is created test2.iso but instead of doing 0ko 3GB ^ ^.)

Here is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FFilehandle: THANDLE;
  FFileMap: THANDLE;
  FmappingPtr: pchar;
  hFile2:    THANDLE ;
  SizeFile1,BytesWritten: DWORD ;
begin
  FFilehandle := CreateFile('titan.iso',
    GENERIC_WRITE OR GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0);
  if (FFilehandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
  begin
    FFileMap := CreateFileMapping(FFileHandle, // handle to file to map
      nil, // optional security attributes
      PAGE_READWRITE, // protection for mapping object
      0, // high-order 32 bits of object size
      2*1024, // low-order 32 bits of object size
      0); //
    if (FFileMap <> NULL) then
    begin
      FMappingPtr := MapViewOfFile(FFileMap,
        FILE_MAP_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        0);
      if Assigned(FMappingPtr)   then
      begin
        // Manipulation de FMappingPtr
        hFile2 := CreateFile('test.iso', GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil,
          CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        if (hFile2 <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
        begin
          SizeFile1 := GetFileSize(FFilehandle, NIL); // recupere taille du fichier 1
          WriteFile(hFile2, Fmappingptr, SizeFile1, &BytesWritten, NIL); // Transfert la mémoire mappé dans file 2
          // libere les ressources
        end
        else
          MessageBox(0, 'Impossible de lire le fichier mappé', 'Error', 0);

        UnmapViewOfFile(Fmappingptr);
        CloseHandle(FFileMap);
        CloseHandle(FFilehandle);
        CloseHandle(hFile2);
      end
      else
      begin
        CloseHandle (FFileMap);
        CloseHandle (FFileHandle);
        MessageBox(0, 'Impossible de lire le fichier mappé', 'Error', 0);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      CloseHandle (FFilemap);
      MessageBox(0, 'Impossible de mappe le fichier en mémoire', 'Error', 0);
    end;
  end
  else
    MessageBox(NULL, 'Impossible d''ouvrir le fichier', 'Error', NULL);
end;
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Any reason your're reinventing the wheel here? Why not just use the CopyFile in WinAPI? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Because I need to program a system copy faster as Teracopy or FastCopy

Comment: And *what exactly* didn't work for you? What was the error code? On what step? Did you double-check parameters of CreateFileMapping?

Comment: Titan.iso, my file (3 GB), do not copy. Test2.iso is created but only 0ko and I do not know how to make the copy is done entirely.In addition, the code does not return error

Comment: System file copy will be hard to beat. If you are going to have a chance you need to understand what its weaknesses are. Do you?

Comment: FastCopy and Teracopy outperforms system file copy, why not me? I just want to test the file mapping because apparently the disk is accessed more quickly

Comment: How do they do it? What do they do that system copy doesn't? That's what you need to find out rather than using trial and error.

Comment: @David, @Reality: Or what time consuming operation do the system copy that FastCopy and Teracopy do not ;)

Comment: Why not you? Because you are a self-described beginner, and outperforming OS-provided system functions is not a task for beginners. It's usually not even a task for experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I disagree with the comments to your question, but there are two reasons that fail your code.

First is, you're specifying 2Kb for `dwFileOffsetLow` with `CreateFileMapping` but then passing the entire file size to `WriteFile`. With this mapping view, 'WriteFile' should be called at most with 2Kb for `nNumberOfBytesToWrite`.

Second is, you're not passing the starting address of your file data correct, try this:

```
[...]

FFileMap := CreateFileMapping(FFileHandle, // handle to file to map
  nil, // optional security attributes
  PAGE_READWRITE, // protection for mapping object
  0, // high-order 32 bits of object size
  0, // low-order 32 bits of object size
  0); //
if (FFileMap <> NULL) then
begin
  FMappingPtr := MapViewOfFile(FFileMap,
    FILE_MAP_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    0);
  if Assigned(FMappingPtr)   then
  begin
    // Manipulation de FMappingPtr
    hFile2 := CreateFile('test.iso', GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil,
      CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (hFile2 <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    begin
      SizeFile1 := GetFileSize(FFilehandle, NIL); // recupere taille du fichier 1
      WriteFile(hFile2, Fmappingptr[0], SizeFile1, &BytesWritten, NIL); // Transfert la mémoire mappé dans file 2
      // libere les ressources
    end

[...]
```

BTW, the reason the code is not returning any errors is that you're not checking the return of 'WriteFile'.

Comment: @Sertac I have the error message "unable to read the file mapped"

Comment: @Reality - No, 'FmappingPtr' is not nil if 'MapViewOfFile' is not failing. There're only to changes I made to the code to make it run. One is the call to 'CreateFileMapping' (pass 0 for high-low order of maximum size), the other is pass 'FmappingPtr[0]' instead of 'FMappingPtr' in 'WriteFile'.

Comment: yes i do , but i have this error "unable to read the file mapped" and if i change value low order by "2k" for example, i havent this error :s

Comment: @Reality - If you set low order file size to 2K also set 'SizeFile1' to 2K before calling WriteFile. You should be able to copy the first 2K of the file if everything else is alright.

Comment: @Sertac yes, now my new file test2.iso do 3Ko but how i can do for test2.iso = 3Gb ?

Comment: @Reality - When I try this large a file here, MapViewOfFile fails, GetLastError returning '8' (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125713 *"The size of a mapped view of an object is limited to the largest contiguous block of unreserved virtual memory in the process performing the mapping (at most, 2GB minus the virtual memory already reserved by the process)"*. I guess the sane think to do would be to copy the file with small chunks.

Comment: @Sertac I just tried with a 1.8 GB file, it works perfectly, THANK YOU for your help

Comment: @Reality - You're welcome! :) Note that this restriction only applies to 32bit software.

Answer (score 2):

The system FileCopy does use memory mapped files. If the file is large you can watch the amount of virtual memory decrease on your system as the mapping takes place. There was a 'feature' in Windows Server recently that would use all of the available virtual RAM to build up the mapping.  So... I would use FileCopy (or FileCopyEx) and let the OS decide on the best way to move the data (it is likely to know best).  If you do it in a separate thread you can even do it without stopping your program - and it will be a very quick copy as most CPUs will spend most of the time buffing their nails waiting for the disk/network.

In your example shouldn't you be CreateFileMapping with PAGE_READONLY and MapViewOfFile with FILE_MAP_READ? The pointer returned (FMappingPtr) should point to valid be visible in the debugger - and it should look like you file.

Comment: it's CopyFile rather than FileCopy. And the Ex version has progress callbacks so there's no need for threads.

Comment: That would depend what else you want to do. If you want to do something useful then it may be that having it run on a separate thread may be just what is needed - and it may get to run on a separate core.